# Strange chars....I Want to save this "º" char, but Im saving like "1Âº"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, utf-8

Im doing a pdf upload system, and it is already working fine.

But, Im always giving to the name of pdf a level, this level have always this char "º".

What is happening is when I do the upload, pdf name is saved no with "º" but with "Âº".

Do you know how I can solve this?

```
if(!empty($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'])){             

   $folder = '../pdfs/';    
   $year = date('Y');
   $month = date('m');

   $pdf = $_FILES['pdf'];
   $ext = substr($pdf['name'],-3);
   $f['pdf'] = $f['level'].'.'.$ext;
   move_uploaded_file($pdf['tmp_name'], $folder.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$f['pdf']);
}
```

In my folder, where I save the files, the pdf name is like this: "**1Âº Level**"

In database, I dont have here the code, but it saves also like "**1Âº Level**".

I already change the database to utf8_general_ci, but the problem remains, and dont seems a database problem because, also when I save  the file in a folder I have the same problem...

Comment: Getting `Â` means you've got a character set mismatch. e.g. utf-8 text going into an iso8859 document.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Marc B. Do you know any possibility to solve this?

Comment: Use a proper mail package, like PHPMailer or Swiftmailer. Don't try to build your own mime emails.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry, but I'm still newbie in php, I know php mailer class, because I already used it to send emails, but I do not see how it can be useful for this case. I'm trying to find information about this, but I do not find anything, can you explain better please?

Comment: Sorry. This was intended for a different tab. But basically your filename is in one charset and your filesystem is in another. mb_convert_encoding() can handle the conversion, but first you'll have to figure out the two charsets involved.